# Calling a WebAPI in .net framework from a console application in .net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

This will be a generic question and not about the code. I have created a simple application in.Net Core. Can I call from a .net core application to a WebAPI written in .net framework?

Will there be compatibility problems in this case?

Comment: No, no problems - WebAPI works over HTTP/S so anything that can send HTTP/S requests can call the API.

Comment: If you're calling a WebAPI (i.e., HTTP-based API), compatibility concerns go out the window, right? Cause you're only relying on HTTP, and not on any proprietary RPC/IPC protocol.

Comment: No, there will not be any compatibility issues as you are communicating using the HTTP protocol. For all the client/ server cares the other party could be written in brainfuck and it would still work

Comment: Thanks Everyone. I will be creating a simple WebAPI and will try to consume it from a .net core application to check the same.